# How can i create ajax query with 2 buttons?

Tags: php, ajax

I have a standard form with two buttons and when you click whichever button the php if detect the button with an if statement.

```
<?php

include('db_config.php');

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
    $id  = $_POST['id'];


    $sql = "UPDATE orders SET qty=? WHERE id=?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($qty,$id));

    header('Location: ../order.php');
}

if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM orders WHERE id=?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($id));
}

?>
```

This is my form:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="content-boxes style-two top-column clearfix animated flipInY" style="opacity: 1;">
        <div class="content-boxes-text">
            <form action="php/edit.php" method="post" class="form-inline pull-right editremove-form">    
                <h3>' . $row['itemName'] . '</h3>
                <h4>Total Price: $'.$row['price'].'</h4>    
                <img src="../wholesale/img/sourdough.jpg" class="img-reponsive">
                <p>Our best seller.  Full of flavour.</p>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Qty</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                <input type="number" name="qty" class="form-control" class="qtyitem" value="' . $row['qty'] . '">
                </div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" class="itemid" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'">
                <button type="submit" id="updatebtn" name="update" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                <button type="submit" id="removebtn" name="delete" class="btn btn-primary">Remove</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- //.content-boxes-text -->
    </div>
    <!-- //.content-boxes -->
</div>
```

I am unsure how to pass the submit button name to the php file, or if its even possible to do it that way?

My ajax:

```
$(".editremove-form").on("submit",function(event){
                        event.preventDefault(); 
                        $.ajax({
                                 type: "POST",
                                 url: "php/edit.php",
                                 data: {
                                          id: $(this).find(".itemid").val(),
                                          qty: $(this).find(".qtyitem").val()
                                 },
                                 success: function(data)
                                 {
                                    $.ajax({
                                            type: 'POST',
                                            url: 'php/refreshproduct.php',
                                            data: {dateorderpicker: $('.date-picker').val()},
                                            dataType: 'JSON',
                                            success: function(data)
                                            {
                                                $("#cartrow").html(data.result_1);
                                                $("#otheritems").html(data.result_2);
                                            }
                                    });
                                 }
                            });
                    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is your AJAX code? You can easily capture which button was clicked with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Mani's answer "use input instead of button".
to create an ajax, make an ID or some identifications to your form so you can identify your form.

your Form:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="content-boxes style-two top-column clearfix animated flipInY" style="opacity: 1;">
        <div class="content-boxes-text">
            <form action="php/edit.php" method="post" class="form-inline pull-right editremove-form" id="myFormID">    
                <h3>' . $row['itemName'] . '</h3>
                <h4>Total Price: $'.$row['price'].'</h4>    
                <img src="../wholesale/img/sourdough.jpg" class="img-reponsive">
                <p>Our best seller.  Full of flavour.</p>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Qty</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                <input type="number" name="qty" class="form-control" class="qtyitem" value="' . $row['qty'] . '">
                </div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" class="itemid" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'">
                <input type="submit" id="updatebtn" name="update" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update">
                <input type="submit" id="removebtn" name="delete" class="btn btn-primary" value="Remove">
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- //.content-boxes-text -->
    </div>
    <!-- //.content-boxes -->
</div>
```

your ajax code:

```
$("#myFormID").submit(function(f){
    f.preventDefault(); // prevent page to load when submitting our form

    // post request
    $.post(
        'to_your_post_URL.php', 
        $(this).serialize(), // serialize form data
        function(){
            // do more after sending data
        }
    )
})
```

NOTE: Make sure that you include jQuery

I hope it will help

Comment: First what is serialize for? Second the script does not remove or edit my item. When i do an alert(data); i get undefined index action for both.

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
<button type="submit" id="updatebtn" name="action" value="update" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
<button type="submit" id="removebtn" name="action" value="remove" class="btn btn-primary">Remove</button>
```

And then in your php code, you can use:

```
if($_post['action'] == "update"){
    //
}elseif($_post['action'] == "remove"){
    //
}
```

If you use jQuery Ajax, you should do something like this:

```
$("button[name=action]").click(function(){
    var data = {action: $(this).val()}; // and anything else you want to send
    $.ajax({
        url: "/url",
        type: "post",
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            //
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay but then how can i script ajax to send this properly? Since this is a standard form and the buttons are working like a standard form action.

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` to cancel the submit in your ajax

Comment: Hey mate i have updated to display my ajax, the ajax seems to work but does not remove the item when delete it pressed, so i am presuming its not picking up the button?

Comment: you can remove your `<form>` and use  click event for each button. the click event in my code can be used for two button and each button have different value and different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Use input type as submit instead of button, it may help u to some extent.

```
<input type="submit" id="updatebtn" name="action" value="update" class="btnbtn-primary">Update</input>
<input type="submit" id="removebtn" name="action" value="remove" class="btn btn-primary">Remove</input>
```